# XamlParseException when using User Control

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-4.0, xamlparseexception

I'm facing the following problem:

I have created a user control in XAML that has an x:Name associated because I have some bindings internally that need this name. On the main page I use multiple instances of this user control and all of the sudden a XamlParseException is thrown which tells me that the name is already in use; but this does not happen always.

Does anybody have the same issue? Has anybody an idea on how to resolve this?

---

**Op's update from a comment, below (which may be deleted):**

> As I found out, **this is a known bug of Silverlight**.
>
> My workaround was to avoid the name attribute on user controls that I use multiple times by setting the control itself as DataContext and then I used bindings to get things working.

Comment: Can you create a *small* example which reproduces this issue?

Comment: Can you add a link to this bug and mark as answer?

Comment: This link provides an explanation of the behavior:
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/236040.aspx/1?XAMLParseException+Name+already+exists